# Has the Soviet movie "Grandmaster" ever been translated into English?

Tags: history, film

I am looking for audio or subtitle English translation of [this 1973 movie by director Sergey Mikaelyan](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0382724/). Does anyone know if that is available anywhere?

Comment: Try asking on IMDB, maybe someone there will see the message one day.

Comment: or in http://movies.stackexchange.com/ bound to get a quicker response perhaps

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no translations that I have found.

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0382724/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_dt_dt#akas) only lists the Russian and Polish versions. [Soviet Movies Online](http://sovietmoviesonline.com/en/) hasn't translated it.